# Update a specific variable of a useState array (by its place) in React.js?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, components, state

In my **React.js** functional component, I need to update only one of the variable of a `useState` **array**:

```
let [nums, setNums] = React.useState([0,0,0])
```

to this:

```
let [nums, setNums] = React.useState([0,1,0])
```

without changing the other variables (something like: `setNums(nums[1] = 1)`).

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: If below answers are useful, click the upvote button (▲) to the left of it. If any answered your question, click the checkmark (✓) to accept it (once the system allows that). That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped. Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use index of the element in the array.

```
const handleChange = (targetIndex)=>{
setState(nums.map(element, index) => if(targetIndex === index){ return updated;} return element);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a **shallow copy** using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_array_literals) and **set new value** using `index` on the copied array:

```js
const update = (index, value) => {
  const copy = [...nums]  // Create a copy
  copy[index] = value     // Set new value
  setNums(copy)
}
```

Note that above method is **not** mutating the original data. **A demo:**

```js
const nums = [0, 0, 0]

const copy = [...nums]
copy[1] = 100

console.log(nums, copy)
```

PS: Using `map()` function is not really required in this case because we already know which `index` value should be updated.